# Extracting data using Volley in Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I was learning how to connect APIs in Android Application. I started with displaying JSON data in Application using Volley but I don't know where I am doing the mistake. My JSON file consists of a name.
JSON file link: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e97251e3000006300b6dc2d

activity_main(.xml):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_result1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView  text1;
    RequestQueue mQueue;
    String name;
    String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e97251e3000006300b6dc2d";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result1);
        Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        sendjsonrequest();


    }

    public void sendjsonrequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    name=response.getString("name");
                    text1.setText(name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but what's the error?

Comment: @Blundell I don't know that's why I posted the question. While building it is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fine with 0 errors, there was some problem on the website where I was hosting my testing JSON API. Thank you, everyone, for help.

Btw only use https://www.npoint.io/ to host your test JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works fine. Have you reviewed your logcat? Have you added the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have added Internet permission,The .apk file should display JSON content "bilal khan" but it is not showing it.

Comment: I would try to show the response with a Toast: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();, have you tried it? Can you also show me your logcat? It might be useful.

Comment: I put Toast inside onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) and it started showing me Toast message. It means my error is related to **public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)**